# Why is the time function in c returning milliseconds instead of seconds?

Tags: c, linux

The time function in C is stated to return the number of seconds since epoch on a Linux system.  When I print out the seconds I get 139880488649 seconds but the math does not add up.  What am I missing?

139880488649 sec / 3600sec / 24 hrs / 365 days = 4435.581 years.

I'm off by a factor of 1000.  Is the time not returned in seconds?

```
time_t curTime;

time(&curTime);

printf("sec = %d", curTime);
```

Comment: Your math is right but that value seems wrong. Can we see the relevant code you're using to print that out?

Comment: Show us the code that calls `time()` and prints the value.

Comment: You edited your question. In the original version, the time value was off by a factor of 1000; now it's off by a factor of 100.

Comment: When I run your code, I get (a) a compile-time warning about passing a `time_t` with a `"%d"` format, and (b) the following output: `sec = 1398810994`. Try using `printf("sec = %ld\n", (long)curTime);` And make sure you have `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <time.h>`.

Comment: Try this: http://codepad.org/Udbk1A3s

Comment: Thanks Keith.  I rebooted and reran and now my values are correct without modifying the code.  I have no idea how this is possible but my values are now:  1398811085.

Comment: Does your code have the required `#include` directives? Is it possible that you weren't compiling and executing the code you thought you were? Did you try the modified `printf` call that I suggested (since the one in your code is incorrect)?

Comment: SSS: On your platform, `time_t` is 1/100 seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  1398804886.49 seconds is about 4/29/2014 20:54 or today.  @Keith Thompson A somewhat more portable way to print `time_t` is `printf("sec = %jd", (intmax_t) curTime);`

Comment: @KeithThompson My code does have those two #includes.  I also tried the modified printf and am getting the same correct result now.  I can only attribute this behavior to maybe the code not compiling.

Comment: @chux: Not likely; it's a Linux system, which almost certainly has a POSIX-confirming `time()` function -- and the program started printing seconds after the OP rebooted. Good point about `"%zu"`, but it's  portable only to systems that support it, and some still don't.

Answer (score 3):

The value you show (1,389,880,488,649) is off by a factor of 1000. So it looks, like you get the time in milliseconds.

On *nix and Linux, [`time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) always has and still does return the value in *seconds*.

*Update:*

Linux and POSIX specify the return value of `time()` as seconds since the Epoch, see also [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/time.html). [ISO C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), however, is vague about the return type and only talks about

> implementation’s best approximation to the current calendar time.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that POSIX (which Linux mostly conforms to) specifies that `time()` returns the number of seconds since the epoch, but ISO C leaves the representation unspecified (except that `time_t` is a numeric type capable of representing times).

Comment: @KeithThompson The representation doesn't change, that the time itself is given in seconds.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: No, the ISO C standard does not specify that the value returned by `time()` is in seconds. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.27.2.4.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, you're right. But it also states that the return type is `time_t`, which is used in `struct timespec`. And `struct timespec` has a member `time_t tv_sec` with a comment saying "whole seconds — ≥ 0". So, while they are vague about the value returned by `time()`, you might conclude, that it is seconds.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Read the footnote: "The **`tv_sec`** member is a linear count of seconds and may not have the normal semantics of a **`time_t`**. The semantics of the members and their normal ranges are expressed in the comments." (`struct timespec` wasn't added to the C standard until 2011.)

Comment: Assuming the original 1389880488649 time-stamp is in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 results in a time of 1/16/2014 13:54.  Assuming the updated time-stamp 139880488649 is in centiseconds since Jan 1, 1970 results in a time of 4/29/2014 20:54 - today.  "time always has and still does return the value in seconds." is not correct.   It is not specified by C11 nor its predecessors.  Any numeric is acceptable.  Non-seconds unit on various platforms come up from time-to-time.